# A way to detect which page a post is on

Tags: posts, pagination

I'm wondering if there is a good way to tell which archive page a post came from. I essentially just need the post's position in the total order, then divide it by the 'posts_per_page' option. The hangup I'm having is getting that position or offset of where the post sits.

EDIT: All while being on the SINGLE POST template.

There, no matter what, the usual $wp_query global and 'page'/'paged' query vars are always 0 - so those won't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, nevermind. I got this solved by doing this at the top of the single post template:

```
$position_query = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'numberposts' => -1 );
$position_posts = get_posts($position_query); $count = 0;
foreach ($position_posts as $position_post) { $count++;
    if ($position_post->ID == $current_id) { $position = $count; break; }
}
$posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
$result = $position/$posts_per_page;
$current_page = ceil($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on page 2+, you'll have access to the `global $page`, which should tell you the pagenumber you're currently on. There're also some others that are worth a look (never know where which one is present/active): `global $multipage, $numpages;`.

You can also check the current page via the [`get_query_var();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) core function. Basically the `global $page` comes from there.

```
// Using get_query_var()
$paged = get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : false;

// Or via the global wp_query object
$paged = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query_vars['page'] ? $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query_vars['page'] : false;

if ( $paged )
    // do stuff - @example echo "Current page is {$paged}";
```

Comment: nice, I didn't know about these globals! -- I should have been more specific in my question though. I'm trying to find which page it belongs to while on the single template. -- my answer to my own question works, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Easy: See update.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this for singles only and slightly simplified the accepted answer:

```
  $position_query = array( 'post_type' => 'post','order'=>'DESC', 'numberposts' => -1 );
  $position_posts = get_posts($position_query); $count = 0;

  foreach ($position_posts as $position_post) { $count++;
        if ($position_post->ID == $post->ID) { $current_page = $count; break; }
   }

  $total_posts = count($position_posts);
```

This can used in this context: 'Page 1 of 10' 1 being $current_page and 10 being $total_posts

Answer (score 0):

When faced with this same requirement I opted to use a direct MySQL call to calculate which page the current post is on without retrieving and looping every post in this post_type. I went this route because I discovered it is much faster when working on a site with thousands of posts.

This approach may also be put inside a function/method and determined from anywhere.

```
function which_page_is_this_post_on( \WP_Post $post ) : int {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*) / %d) from {$wpdb->posts} WHERE `ID` <= %d and post_type=%s and post_status='publish'", get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), $post->ID, $post->post_type ) );
}
```

If you find you are calling it often (like within a template) you can store the result in the object cache if desired.

```
function which_page_is_this_post_on( \WP_Post $post ) : int {
    global $wpdb;
    $cached = wp_cache_get( __FUNCTION__ . $post->ID );
    if ( ! $cached  ) {
        $cached = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT CEIL(COUNT(*) / %d) from {$wpdb->posts} WHERE `ID` <= %d and post_type=%s and post_status='publish'", get_option( 'posts_per_page' ), $post->ID, $post->post_type ) );
        wp_cache_set( __FUNCTION__ . $post->ID, $cached, 15 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
    }
    return $cached;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We have 2 Conditional Tags to make this simpler

```
 <?php if(is_single())
    {
    echo "post";
    }
    elseif(is_page())
    {
    echo "page";
    } ?>
```

Paste This in the File which includes in both page and post and changed from "post" & "Page" to whatever your need is.